# supremum and infimum proof

Tags: real-analysis, supremum-and-infimum

$$A=\left\{\frac{2^n}{3^k}: n,k \in \Bbb N,\ n \le k\right\}$$
I'd say that $\sup A=1$ (for $n=k=0$) and $\inf A=0$. I have problem with proving this. Generally I have problem with proofs that include epsilon.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: I changed $infA$ and $supA$ to $\inf A$ and $\sup A$, using \inf and \sup.  That is standard.

Comment: Have you already done some limits of sequences or not yet? I ask just to be dead sure, as this material usually preceedes limits.

Comment: yes, I'm studying for resit :(
I know that if we take $n=k$ then $\lim \frac{2^n}{3^n}=0$. Can this be used as proof? And I bet there is some explaination needed.

Answer (score 1):

**Hints:**

- To prove that something is the supremum of a set, you need to show that it is both an upper bound and a least upper bound.  To show that $1$ is an upper bound, note that
  $$
  2^n \le 3^n \le 3^k.
  $$
  Then to show it is the smallest upper bound, show it is in fact an element of the set.
- Similarly, to prove the infemum is $0$, you need to show that $0$ is a lower bound and the greatest lower bound.  It should be easy to see why it is a lower bound.  Then you need to show that any $\epsilon > 0$ is *not* a lower bound; to do so, note that there exists $n$ such that $\epsilon > \frac{1}{3^n}$.

Comment: And thus in fact $\;1\;$ is the set's *maximum*. +1

Comment: Sorry. I understand your hints, but I have problem with writing this proof in a formal way. I know that there exist $n,k$ that let $\frac{2^n}{3^k}$ be as close to $0$ as we want to, but I don't know how to explain this clearly.

Comment: @miko As I sad, note that there exists $n$ such that $\epsilon > \frac{1}{3^n}$.  You don't have to justify why this is true.  Are you looking for a justification of that, or do you not understand where to go from there?

Comment: I do not know where to go from there.

Comment: @miko If $S$ is a set, the definition of $\inf S = 0$ is (1) that $0$ is a lower bound, and (2) that for all $\epsilon > 0$, there exists $x \in S$ such that $x < \epsilon$.  For part (1), you just need to show for any $k, n$ that $\frac{2^k}{3^n} \ge 0$.  For part (2), to show THERE EXISTS an $x$ you pick one, namely $\frac{1}{3^n}$.  Then since $\frac{1}{3^n} < \epsilon$, you are done.

Answer (score 0):

We know intuitively that as $k$ gets really big, the fraction goes to 0. How big does $k$ have to be to get below $\frac{1}{2}$? At $k=2$, $\frac{4}{9}<\frac{1}{2}$.

What about to get below $\frac{1}{3}$? For $k=3$, $\frac{8}{27}<\frac{1}{3}$.

Try continuing this approach. Think of  $\epsilon$ as $\frac{1}{N}$ for $N$ some big number